# How to login/logout in flutter pub publish?

Tags: flutter-packages

I am trying to publish upgrade for my package and getting error:

```
Insufficient permissions to upload new versions of package...
```

I am signed in in Chrome to pub.dev with account that is administrator in publisher for the package.

How can I check what is current account in 'flutter pub', and switch to right account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sign out, you need to locate and delete credentials.json from your `flutter/.pub-cache`. It is hidden, so you need to press Command+Shift+Dot, if do it in Mac Finder.

After you signed out, run 'flutter pub publish' and it will guide you through sign in process.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
pub logout
```

... and then you can try publishing again:

```
pub publish
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do It, I would recommend this

Answer (score 5):

Run `flutter pub logout` to logout and `flutter pub login` to login.